# Why my webservice not live on internet?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7

I've windows server that goes live on internet, (e.g. www.mysite.com). Then I want to create another site with different port (e.g. www.mysite.com:502). I've create that and it works when I access it on local network, but when I access it from outside of local network (internet) the www.mysite.com:502 can't accessed but the www.mysite.com can accessed. what should I do to make www.mysite.com:502 goes online? I use windows server 2008 standard

Answer (score 1):

You will probably have to get your network administrator involved to forward the appropriate ports to your server.

Also, why are you using different ports for different websites?
Even IIS should be able to host multiple vhosts on the same IP & port pair.

Comment: ok, I will involve my network admin to create my site. i use different port, because I follow previous site on this server all site have URL like this www.mysite.com:501 , www.mysite.com:502 , etc. all of them use different port and to access them I need permission, and the site that I want to create is open for all so I use different port. any suggestion for this condition? btw thank you for your answer

Comment: Well, what you're doing is not *wrong* per sé, just atypical. You could technically host all of them on port 80 and prevent unauthorized access using basic HTTP authentication. I have no actual IIS expertise, so I'll just leave [this](http://www.google.com/search?q=http+basic+auth+iis7) here. ;-)

Comment: but I don't have permission to change the previous site port or change any previous site. but thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Have the ports on the router been forwarded?

Comment: I don't know because I'm not the network admin, so what I should to do? should I call my network admin to forward the port? BTW, on my server there are several websites with the same hostname but diffetent ports, and all of them are online. then I want to create another one with unused port.